# Meteor Bootstrap container height: 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've got the following files:

**mainLayout.html**

```
<template name="mainLayout">
{{> header}}
<div class="container">
</div>
</template>
```

**mainLayout.css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

for clarification here a image:

[image]

Did I something wrong with the html,body tags in the css file, in the html file they are not included because I use a template.

Thanx for any help!

Comment: What is your question? Are you wondering why the height of the DIV is not 100%?

Comment: If you are wanting it to be 100%, you need to make sure each enclosing element is set to 100% as well, such as `<div class="__blaze_root">`

Comment: Thanx for the answer, this was the solution!